# Publish Excel sheet to SharePoint with linked images

Tags: image, excel, vba, sharepoint, publish

I have an Excel workbook with a bunch of Sheets, that I would like to publish to different SharePoint sub-sites within a sites hierarchy.

I have written a VBA procedure that does that, but unfortunately it does not work correctly, because the sheets have images and Excel tries to copy them by creating the "*_files" structure, which I DO NOT WANT! The images are already on the server, and I would only need Excel to use their URLs and everything would by fine with just creating the plain HTML without any "*_files" folder.

If I keep it like that, Excel tries to generate the PNGs for the files but failes for some reason and they come out 0B long. It works fine for local paths or even different server paths, so I don't know the reason.

Anyone has an idea?

*EDIT:*

It seems that setting `ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.OrganizeInFolder = False` solves ar least the problem with displaying the images. Excel keeps copying the images, generating useless clutter, but at least the rendering is ok...

Do also remember to set `ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.RelyOnVML= False`, otherwise the page will not work outside IE.

Comment: Have you tried the MS URL from the comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14916020/1569434

Comment: Yes, thanks. It doesn't really help in keeping the link to the image. With any setting, Excel just automatically tries to copy the image to the server and does it wrong...

Comment: It seems that setting `ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.OrganizeInFolder = False` solves ar least the problem with displaying the images. Excel keeps copying the images, generating useless clutter, but at least the rendering is ok... Do also remember to set `ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.RelyOnVML= False`, otherwise the page will not work outside IE.